# Language concatenation

Tags: automata, regular-language

We learned in class that the regular languages are closed under concatenation (e.g $L_1L_2   =\{ w_1w_2 : w_1 \in L_1,w_2 \in L_2\}$ is a regular language if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are also regular languages).

> My question is: why is there a language : $L' = \{ww: w \in L\}$ which is not regular if $L$ is a regular language? Is it not just a special case where $L_1 = L_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The problem is that $L'$ isn't the concatenation $L\circ L$, since it's made up to the concatenation of each word in $L$ *with itself*. It would be if we had defined it as
$$
\{xy\mid x\in L, y\in L\}
$$
but a string is in $L'$ if it's of the form $ww$: two copies of a word in $L$. That's clearly not a regular language in general, since you could take as an example $L=\{\mathtt{0}^n\mathtt{1}\mid n\ge 0\}$ and then 
$$
L'=\{\mathtt{0}^n\mathtt{1}\mathtt{0}^n\mathtt{1}\mid n\ge 0\}
$$
which a simple Pumping Lemma proof would show that isn't regular. Intuitively, the language above would require a finite automaton that could count the number of zeros in a string, which we know is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand perfectly your example and I understand that L' is not regular. It is correct to say that the language $ww$ is a subset of $xy$ ?

Comment: @automata123. Indeed.